# Splitting a table on comma separated emails in Big Query

Tags: sql, regex, split, google-bigquery

I have a table with following columns (The email address are comma separated):

```
+---------+----------+------------+---------------------------------------------+---------+
| Sr. No. |  Domain  | Store Name |                    Email                    | Country |
+---------+----------+------------+---------------------------------------------+---------+    
| 1.      | kkp.com  | KKP        | den@kkp.com, info@kkp.com, reno@kkp.com     | US      |
| 2.      | lln.com  | LLN        | silo@lln.com                                | UK      |
| 3.      | ddr.com  | DDR        | info@ddr.com, dave@ddr.com                  | US      |
| 4.      | cpp.com  | CPP        | hello@ccp.com, info@ccp.com, stelo@ccp.com  | CN      |
+---------+----------+------------+---------------------------------------------+---------+
```

I want the output with Email in separate Columns:

```
+---------+----------+------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------+---------+
| Sr. No. |  Domain  | Store Name |    Email 1    |    Email 2    |    Email 3    | Email N | Country |
|---------+----------+------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------+---------+
| 1.      | kkp.com  | KKP        | den@kkp.com   | info@kkp.com  | reno@kkp.com  | ....... | US      |
| 2.      | lln.com  | LLN        | silo@lln.com  |               |               | ....... | UK      |
| 3.      | ddr.com  | DDR        | info@ddr.com  | dave@ddr.com  |               | ....... | US      |
| 4.      | cpp.com  | CPP        | hello@ccp.com | info@ccp.com  | stelo@ccp.com | ....... | CN      |
+---------+----------+------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------+---------+
```

Can someone please help a beginner in SQL and BigQuery.

Comment: can you show your code effort?

Comment: @Rahulvats . . . A SQL query has a fixed set of columns.  Do you know how many email columns you will need?